# no matching function for call to ‘regex_search(...)'

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, g++4.9

Given an old-style `const char *` pointer and a length, is there a way to call `std::regex_search()` on it without first copying the contents of the buffer into a `std::string`?  Here is a simple example of the problem I have:

```
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    const char *text = "123 foobar 456";
    const size_t len = strlen(text);

    const std::regex rx(" (.+)bar");

    std::smatch what;
    std::regex_search( text, text+len, what, rx); // <- problematic line

    return 0;
}
```

I thought the 5th [std::regex_search()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/) that takes two iterators is what I need, but I'm not fully understanding how to convert pointers to iterators.  When I try to compile the code above, I get this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
test.cpp:11:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘regex_search(const char*&, const char*, std::smatch&, const regex&)’
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/regex.h:2131:5: note: template<class _Bi_iter, class _Alloc, class _Ch_type, class _Rx_traits> bool std::regex_search(_Bi_iter, _Bi_iter, std::match_results<_BiIter, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_regex<_CharT, _TraitsT>&, std::regex_constants::match_flag_type)
 regex_search(_Bi_iter __s, _Bi_iter __e,
```

...and a lot more errors!

Can `const char *` be converted to the necessary iterator?  Did I do it wrong?  Am I misunderstanding how this works?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error in your code is that you're using the wrong [`match_results`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results) type. `smatch` is supposed to be used when you have an `std::string` object and you're passing `std::string::iterator`s to the `regex` function. When you have raw `char const *`s use `cmatch` instead.

Change

```
std::smatch what;
```

to

```
std::cmatch what;
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22dda98a35b60e95)