# std::regex_search with assigned length char* parameter doesn't work in VS2017?

Tags: c++, regex, stl, std

I found this code seems to work well
[no matching function for call to ‘regex_search(...)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28018959/no-matching-function-for-call-to-regex-search)

My code

```
    char* s = "123abcd";
    std::cmatch pieces_match;
    bool b = std::regex_search(s, pieces_match, std::regex("[^0-9]")); // works well
    for (auto& sub : pieces_match)
    {
        cout << sub << endl;
    }
    b = std::regex_search(s, s+2, pieces_match, std::regex("[^0-9]")); // Error C2672   'std::regex_search': no matching overloaded function found      
    for (auto& sub : pieces_match)
    {
        cout << sub << endl;
    }
```

The first regex_search worked well. The second with assigned length char* parameter didn't work. Why?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a const char* parameter.

```
const char* s = "123abcd";
```